# MeteorJS: why takes so long in foreach? Should I use MongoDB aggregation operations, how?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where a single doc is like this:

```
{
    _id: 'string'
    date: Date,
    user: 'usera',
    sections: [
        { heading: 'string a', score: 10 },
        { heading: 'string a', score: 104 },
        { heading: 'string b', score: 123 },
        { heading: 'string b', score: 15 },
        { heading: 'string b', score: 7 },
        { heading: 'string c', score: 1 }
    ]
    totalScore: 259
}
```

The collection has hundreds of thousands of documents.

I need to search from collection by date and give sum of scores in sections and the sum of `totalScores`.

In Meteor publications if I do this

```
Meteor.publish('mydata', function() {
  var rets = {}

  Mycollections.find({date: {$gte: new Date(2016, 8, 1), $lt: new Date (2016, 12, 24)}}.forEach(function (doc) {
     if (!rets[doc.user]) {
       rets[doc.user] = {

         tot: 0, 
         sections: {}
       }
     }

     rets[doc.user].tot += doc.totalScore;
     for (var i in doc.sections) {
        if (!rets[doc.user].sections[doc.sections[i].heading]) {
          sections[doc.sections[i].heading] = 0;
        }

        rets[doc.user].sections[doc.sections[i].heading] += sections[doc.sections[i].score; 
     }
  });

  return rets;

});
```

`Mycollections.find({date: {$gte: new Date(2016, 8, 1), $lt: new Date (2016, 12, 24)}}` takes less  than 0 ms to execute.

For single forEach-loop it takes about 0-1ms to execute, if I fetch 20 000 docs, it gets 20 seconds to publish.

**How would MongoDB aggregates help here?** or how could I perform calculations faster server side ?

What I need is a sum of total scores and sum of scores in each sections for every users in collection.

```
{
  usera: {
   tot: 235
   sections[
    {'string a': 200},
    {'string b': 35},
    {...}
  ]
 }, 
 userb: {
 ...
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform an aggregation for :

- matching your date range
- computing `totalScore` per user
- computing `score` per sections
- group by `user` and get an array of sections with the scores in it

This could be composed of :

- `$match` for your date range
- `$group` to compute `totalScore` and push `$$ROOT` document to a new field to keep track for the next group
- `$unwind` the `$$ROOT` document to convert the array into json object
- `$unwind` the sections array to have one line per sections record (ready to be grouped)
- `$group` to sum all sections score by `user` & by `sections`
- `$group` to regroup all sections score into one record per `user`

The query is :

```
db.document.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        date: {
            $gte: ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00.0Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2016-12-24T23:59:00.0Z")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "user": "$user"
        },
        totalScore: { $sum: "$totalScore" },
        document: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$document"
}, {
    $unwind: "$document.sections"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "user": "$_id.user",
            "sections": "$document.sections.heading"
        },
        score: { $sum: "$document.sections.score" },
        totalScore: { $first: "$totalScore" }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.user",
        sections: { $push: { "name": "$_id.sections", "score": "$score" } },
        totalScore: { $first: "$totalScore" }
    }
}])
```

It gives you something like that :

```
{ "_id" : "userc", "sections" : [ { "name" : "string c", "score" : 1 }, { "name" : "string b", "score" : 145 }, { "name" : "string a", "score" : 114 } ], "totalScore" : 259 }
{ "_id" : "usera", "sections" : [ { "name" : "string c", "score" : 12 }, { "name" : "string b", "score" : 1873 }, { "name" : "string a", "score" : 230 } ], "totalScore" : 269 }
```

In Meteor, you can perform the aggregation with :

```
MyCollection.aggregate(
    // aggregation query here
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new in MongoDB aggregations, and that $$ROOT -part was totally new for me and grouping three times. Now this whole query will run in 50ms! Merry x-mas!